# Take a photo of the webcam in JavaScript and send it to the database

Tags: javascript

** I take a photo of the user using the webcam. And I convert this photo to a file so I can send it to the server. I use form data to send this file and it gives me a 400 warning **

```js
async  function postImage(url, _image) {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: _image
    });
    let uploadImage = await response.json();
    return uploadImage;
}


let video = document.getElementById('video');
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

let cameraStream = null;

if (null == cameraStream) {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
            .then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
                cameraStream = stream;
            })
    }
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}

document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener('click', () => {
    video.style.display = 'none';

    if (null != cameraStream) {
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5);
        let file = dataURItoBlob(img);

        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        let track = cameraStream.getTracks()[ 0 ];
        track.stop();
        video.load();
        cameraStream = null;

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("objectable",'attendance_times')
        formData.append("filePath", file, "image.png");

        for (var value of formData.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        setTimeout(()=>{
            postImage(base_url+'/api/media', formData)
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },2000)

    }

})
```

```html
        <video id="video" width="400" height="400" autoplay></video>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="snap">snap photo</button>
```

**Unfortunately, I have trouble sending this file**
**I don't know where the problem with this code is. Please help if this problem can be fixed**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your post is going to work that way. Perhaps have a look at the [formdata](https://javascript.info/formdata#sending-a-form-with-blob-data) object.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tested your answer. But there is still a problem.